# Sumif function and copy value to workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a procedure to get the values from a Sumif but I am not able to copy and paste the value to another workbook. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my WIP:

```
Sub WLPTdata()

Dim NEO As Range

NEO = Application.SumIf(Range("C7:C3000"), "TM-NEO", Range("K7:K3000"))

Selection.Copy

Windows("HSD_PTdata.xlsx").Activate
 Sheets("pdata").Select
Range("B160").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: What is the exact problem?  Error?  No value?  Incorrect value?

Answer (score 3):

NEO should be defined as a Double or a Long, depending on the data that you expect from the SumIf.

then you can assign that value with

```
workbooks("HSD_PTdata.xlsx").Sheets("pdata").range("B160")=NEO
```

or, you can do it in a single line

```
Range("[HSD_PTdata.xlsx]pdata!B160")=Application.SumIf(Range("C7:C3000"), "TM-NEO", Range("K7:K3000"))
```

assuming you're starting the Sum on the appropriate sheet. If not, change your range in the sumif to include the complete reference, such as `"[Book1]Sheet2!C7:C300"`